# cant access JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have this ajax request,

```
$.ajax({
    url    : '<?php echo current_url(); ?>',
    data       : "txtKeywords="+$("#txtKeywords").val()+"&search=Search For Item",
    type       : 'POST',
    dataType   : 'JSON',
    success : function(html)
    {       
        console.log(html);          
    }
});
return false;
```

I get the following in my console,

```
[{"productId":"5","productTitle":"Small Brasserie Dining Table","productPath":"small-brasserie-dining-table\/","productRangeId":"6","productSecondaryRangeId":"0","productTypeId":"2","productRefNo":"0080","productShortDesc":"","productBestSeller":"0","productFeatured":"0","productIsSet":"0","productPrice":"275","productSavingType":"none","productSavingPrice":"0","productSavingMessage":"","productDimWidth":"90","productDimHeight":"74","productDimDepth":"90","productTechnical":"Powder coated aluminium frame with welded joints.","productTemplateId":"5","productMetadataTitle":"","productMetadataKeywords":"","productMetadataDescription":"","productBandingColour":"grey","productActualPrice":"275","rangeTitle":"Dining","parentRangeTitle":"Aegean","fullRangePath":"aegean\/dining\/","fullProductPath":"aegean\/dining\/small-brasserie-dining-table\/","hasImage":"0"}]
```

But when I do something like,

```
alert(html.productTitle)
```

all I get is undefined?

What am I doing wrong?j

Comment: I guess you need parse string into json object using `JSON.parse`.

Comment: By current_url, are you trying to make an Ajax Call to the same page that's making the call in the first place?  It doesn't error for me, but that also doesn't work!

Answer (score 6):

Is it because your `html` variable is an array? Wouldn't you have to do...

```
alert(html[0].productTitle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try html[0].productTitle, I have run into this problem a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Jquery's JSON ajax function instead of the $.ajax it will parse the JSON for you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 0):

try doing something like this:

`alert(html.d); // this will show the result of your ajax call`

i don't know what the reason is to use the property 'd' but if you can take a look at your result, use a debug tool to see what data is getting back your ajax call.

if you want convert your JSON string to and object, you can do with the following code:

`var respuesta = jQuery.parseJSON(html.d);`